# how to get location from another device by internet in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to make two simple android apps to get one's location into another android device by internet. I have already learned how to get location on same device but i have no idea how to get another device's location. Please guide me to the topics and i will learn more. I am new in android and thanks in advance.

thanks again

Comment: if you have code of getting device location then just create Service class in app that get location and send to another device.

Comment: What do you want to say?

Comment: just get your device location and send that to another user. same for another user

Comment: i don't have server like whatsapp etc so i think i will have to open socket on my phone and wait for another device to send data. am i right ?

Comment: if you want to save location then use 000webhost or 1freehosting server.

Comment: bro i actually don't know how to send data to another user using TCP/UDP IP connection

Comment: then use php or for push notification use firebase console.

Comment: i can guide you if u want.

Comment: yes please Divyesh

Comment: so how you want to send location info? notification to another user?

Comment: i think it is also a good idea if i can save data to some server online and then get it .

Comment: then u can use firebase console, it can give notification as well as database for saving location infos.